# Guzzel Exception - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl, guzzle

I'm trying to get a response for the API endpoint but it's resulting in an error saying that

> Server error: `POST http://base_url/api/servicebookingrequest`
>   resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:\n{\"Message\":\"An
>   error has occurred.\"}\n",

I just added the code that so far writtern

```
try {
        \Validator::make($req->all(), [
            'chassis_no' => 'string',
            'registration_no' => 'string',
            'dealer_code' => 'string',
            'pick_and_drop' => 'string',
            'pick_address' => 'string',
            'drop_address' => 'string',
            'booking_date' => 'date',
            'expected_service_date' => 'date',
            'timeslots' => 'string',
        ]);
        $client = new Client();
        $res = $client->request(
            'POST',
            'http://bas_url/api/servicebookingrequest',
            [
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                    '_token' => csrf_token()
                ],
                'form_params' => [
                    'ChassisNo' => $req->chassis_no,
                    'RegistrationNo' => $req->registration_no,
                    'DealerCode' => $req->dealer_code,
                    'PickAndDrop' => $req->pick_and_drop,
                    'PickAddress' => $req->pick_address,
                    'DropAddress' => $req->drop_address,
                    'BookingDate' => $req->booking_date,
                    'ExpectedServiceDate' => $req->expected_service_date,
                    'MultiSlotSelected' => $req->timeslot,
                ]
            ]
        );
        $res_body = $res->getBody()->getContents();
        $res_body = json_decode($res_body, true);
        response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'response' =>$res_body ]);
    } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e) {
        response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'response' => $e->getMessage()]); ;
    }
```

But I tried the same API endpoint in `postman` its giving proper response from the server.

Update:- Curl also working fine.

Any help to solve the issue is really appreciated
Thanks

Comment: You should add code for the server side.

Comment: Could you please breaf.? The only problem with guzzle except for postman and Curl are working fine

Comment: A `500 Internal Server Error` can mean anything. It shows, that your request at least reaches the target endpoint. Other than that only the server side will help you find your issue.

Comment: I'd recommend some logging on the server side if you can, which would help identify where the receiving end breaks.

Comment: Please check server logs and add some more information.

Comment: @Psychemaster Yah its client/third party server. Issue fixed..

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the server side code, since the same endpoint works with both the `curl` and `postman`. The issue can be related to the way you are using the `Guzzle` to send requests to the endpoint. Try to change the request option from `form-params` to [multipart/form-data](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#multipart).